# Understanding code and key keywords in Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am following [this](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/choropleth_basic.html) `d3.js` example.

However I am struggling to understand this line:

```
.defer(d3.csv, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world_population.csv", function(d) { data.set(d.code, +d.pop); })
```

What are `d.code` and `d.pop` doing here?

What are `code` and `pop` standing for exactly?

Comment: They are being passed to `data.set` when the callback function is called. `d.pop` is also being converted to a number using the unary plus operator.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So they are just the column names in the array? When I tried to use my own data in the same format and names it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [look at that file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world_population.csv) you'll see that it is a CSV with three columns: `name`, `code`, and `pop`:

```
name,code,pop
Antigua and Barbuda,ATG,83039
Algeria,DZA,32854159
Azerbaijan,AZE,8352021
Albania,ALB,3153731
...
```

D3 is reading the file and, for each row, creating an object with properties named based on the header row in the file and passing that object to the callback. The callback is converting `d.pop` from string to number and calling `data.set` to put the data in the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the link

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world_population.csv

you can see it's a CSV file consisting of the country its area code and the population on the map for the area. In short its

`d.code` -> Area code of the country

`d.pop` -> Population of the country which is getting used for creating the choropleth map